# Generate report for the comparision results in c#

Tags: c#, html, xml, reporting, report

I have Input A , Input B and Output C (all are different files) based on a condition, i can know if it failed, or passed etc (using c#)..

Now i need to report the results for all input files, in a user friendly way,

ie

```
Input A1 with Input B1 gives Output C1 -- Failed
Input A2 with Input B2 gives Output C2 -- Passed
```

where all the these names above should be hyperlinks for those files..

which is the best way to achieve this?? (since i need hyperlinks, its best if the report is opened it a browser) Is there any library/framework available already.. (i currently use c#)
Im looking for an opensource option if such a thing is available..

Thanks,

Comment: It will be better if it can be sorted (based on say folder, or result or amount of failure etc), and all failed will be in RED color etc...

Comment: I don't think you should expect anything which will just do it all for you, but it sounds like pretty simple HTML generation - which bit are you finding hard?

Comment: @jon thanks for replying, just tell me a good direction to proceed, im new to this, i dont want a implemented solution, i just want to go in the right direction..

Comment: i mean i dont want to follow some path and at the end find that there is a better way to do that.. so hoping to get expert suggestions here :)

Comment: My suggestion would just be to build it from hand. I wouldn't expect it to take too long, to be honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it look a bit professional, i used the approach used in the APIREPORT from codeproject site,
[link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43244/Genius-Open-HTML-Generator-How-To-Easily-Create-an)

Thank You :)